# Creating clone table in hibernate java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a sample table as follows

```
+ Tbl_template
   -id
   -name
```

and POJO in hibernate is **class TblTemplate**

I want to create some tables that have the same structure as the tbl_template table use the same POJO **class TblTemplate**

```
-tbl_template_1 (id / name)
-tbl_template_2 (id / name)
...
-tbl_template_3 (id / name)
```

If I want to create,update,delete data to any table I call that table by table name

If using sql would be easier but I would like to use HQL or hibernate builtin functions

I searched for commands or documents that could do it, but I did not succeed
.Please help me!

Comment: You really should stop and rethink this design. Its going to stink a lot. Many tables with the same structure is bad news. Just stick with one table and add another one to classify it like tbl_template_type and add a FK on your tbl_template.

Comment: Actually it is not bad in some cases

For example: I'm wanting to use it to save the information the web pages I analyze from source code with jsoup ==> I think it's better to keep one table

Comment: It **is** bad, believe me. Just add another table "website" and a FK to or from the table template.

Comment: I understand your mind, but I'm a bit nervous

Because my database stores information I obtained from a website, for example youtube

If I use foreign key as you say I will have the following two tables

-tblChannel: channel_url
-tblVideoContent: title, description, channel_url (FK-> tblChannel)

My problem is that if I have more than 10000 channel_url then the tblVideoContent table will be huge.

I need a lot of access to the tblVideoContent table as I think the program will be very slow

Comment: And when the data stream with status was used is 1, I do not need to use it but I still need to filter it for the first run to get the status equal to 0.

Comment: That's why partition tables exists to solve such problems. But hey, do as you please. It is just an advice from someone with many miles in the road... Cheers...

Comment: Thank you @Jorge Campos for the first time I know of the partition table concept, I have not yet understood it but it looks like it is a good choice for me, I am learning it.

Do you have other techniques like partition table that can help me?

Comment: Well to help you better I would need to understand your problem and why are trying to do what you want right now. So take your time, edit your question if information about your problem and why you are trying to follow this path (multiple tables), then I or someone else here will help you for sure.

Comment: Hihi That's a general question for database huge,I am feeling
happy with your technical partition table :D